# Implementing a poor man's throttling queue with NFS

Tags: concurrency, nfs

I need to run thousands of tasks, each on its dedicated (slurm) cluster node.

At certain times, the tasks need to fetch huge files from a centralized disk via NFS.

I would like to implement a throttling mechanism so that at most N tasks can be fetching from the centralized NFS disk at any given time.

Tasks cannot access the network, so options are limited, the NFS drive is the only means of coordination.

I'm thinking of implementing a poor man's throttling queue with NFS as follow:

```
   while count("ls /centralized_nfs/throttle_1/*") > N:
      sleep(random(5, 20) seconds)

   touch "/centralized_nfs/throttling_1/$TASK_ID"

   while count("ls /centralized_nfs/throttle_2/*") > N:
      sleep(random(5, 20) seconds)

   touch "/centralized_nfs/throttling_2/$TASK_ID"
   
   huge_copy()

   rm "/centralized_nfs/throttling_1/$TASK_ID"
   rm "/centralized_nfs/throttling_2/$TASK_ID"
```

1. $TASK_ID is a unique identifier for the tasks
2. throttling_1 and throttling_2  are shared directories on the shared drive
3. N is the max concurent download desired

The reason for using 2 checks in 2 directories, is that there could ba a race condition with a single check, for ex. a scenario where all nodes read before the "touch", count zero files, and start copying.

In theory, the double check does not eliminate the probability of the race condition, but it reduces it drasticaly. It seems "good enough" in practice.

I'm trying to think of a better algo with zero probability of race conditions, so far I didn't find any.